# Why does jq allow range() function to accept comma as arguments separator when semi-colon is documented?

Tags: function, syntax, jq

I'm trying to find out why the `range()` function in `jq` allows arguments separated by `,` when the more general style is to separate arguments by `;` for other functions? I know for a fact that if `sub()` or other functions used with `,` would throw a not-defined error most likely due to prototype mismatch.

But why is range behaving this way for the `range(from;upto)` prototype

```
$ jq -n 'range(0; 4)'
0
1
2
3
```

and

```
$ jq -n 'range(0, 4)'
0
1
2
3
```

For `range(from;upto;by)` using `,` misbehaves, but I would still like a warning to be thrown nevertheless.

```
# runs as if did range(0; 2)
$ jq -n 'range(0, 4; 2)'
0
1
```

and

```
# runs as if did range(0; 4) + range(0; 2)
$ jq -n 'range(0; 4, 2)'
0
1
2
3
0
1
```

This is seen in both `jq-1.6` and `jq-1.5`. Since the official documentation does not talk about type the prototype involving `,` and is not likely a bug, how should the behavior with `,` be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, jq defines range/1 as:

```
def range($x): range(0;$x);
```

So range(0,$n) evaluates to

```
range(0), range($n)
```

which yields the stream `empty, range($n)`, which is equivalent to the stream

```
range(0;$n)
```

The main point, perhaps, is that the "comma" operator can be used freely.

Comment: Do you think its worth adding a note about this in the documentation, as the other functions strictly won't accept `,` in their arguments?

Comment: @Inian - The "confusability" of "," and ";" is already covered extensively in the supplementary documentation (notably under the "confusability" heading at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls).  The main documentation is intentionally concise and already covers the comma operator, so I don't think anything additional is needed there.  The uses (and misuses) of the comma operator are all part of the joy of discovery :-)

Comment: @Inian range/1 doesn't even see the comma; as it's defined as range(**$x**), it accepts a single **value**, so when you do `range(3,5)`, JQ evaluates `3,5` and calls range/1 for every individual product of it. If it was defined as `def range(s): [s] | range(.[0];.[1]);`, then it would be correct to say *range/1 accepts a stream as its argument*